# Flex 4.5 - Custom NativeWindow and problems

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I have a class FlexNativeWindow who extends to NativeWindow.
I use this method to create new window on my AIR app.
All works well but some keyboard interraction is not availaible.

For exemple focus arround textinput is not visible.
Key down and up don't work on DropDownList.
TabOrder doesn't work well!

Can you explain Why? Because I'm very desapointed!

Code to create the new window

```
var wdetcorr:wDetailCorrespondant = new wDetailCorrespondant();
                wdetcorr.monIdCorresp = correspDG.selectedItem.crIndex;

                var wOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
                wOptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE;
                wOptions.transparent = false;
                var fnwDetailPatient:FlexNativeWindow = new FlexNativeWindow(wdetcorr, wOptions);
                fnwDetailPatient.active();
```

Code about my custom NativeWindow

```
package fr.int.ui.windowSkin
{
    import flash.display.NativeWindow;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    import mx.core.IUIComponent;
    import mx.core.IVisualElement;
    import mx.core.IVisualElementContainer;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.events.*;
    import mx.managers.WindowedSystemManager;

    [Event(name="creationComplete", type="mx.events.FlexEvent")]

    public class FlexNativeWindow extends NativeWindow implements IFlexNativeWindow
    {
        private var _systemManager:WindowedSystemManager;

        private var _content:UIComponent;

        private var _window:IVisualElementContainer;

        public function FlexNativeWindow(window:IVisualElementContainer, initOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = null)
        {
            super(initOptions);


            _window = window;

            addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, windowActivateHandler);

        }

        public function addElement(control:IVisualElement):void
        {
            _window.addElement(control);
        }

        public function removeElement(control:IVisualElement):void
        {
            _window.removeElement(control);
        }

        private function windowActivateHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            removeEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, windowActivateHandler);

            if (stage)
            {
                if (!_systemManager)
                    _systemManager = new WindowedSystemManager(IUIComponent(_window));

                stage.addChild(_systemManager);

                dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE));

                stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, windowResizeHandler);
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownListener);

            }
        }

        private function keyDownListener (e:KeyboardEvent):void {

            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE) {
                stage.nativeWindow.dispatchEvent(new Event("myEventClose", true));
                stage.nativeWindow.close();
            }


        }

        private function windowResizeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            // prise en compte de la valeur mini
            UIComponent(_window).height = stage.stageHeight;
            UIComponent(_window).width = stage.stageWidth;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding your own WindowedSystemManager (and adding it to the stage)?  I would think that this is probably interfering with the one that Flex creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement `IFocusManagerContainer` in `FlexNativeWindow` to fix the focus issues.

Here is how to do it in Flash Builder:

1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + T` and type in `IFocusManagerContainer`
2. Open corresponding file
3. Implement all declared methods in your class `FlexNativeWindow`

P.S: However this approach can fail because flex components should be placed inside flex container while `NativeWindow` is a native class, not a Flex SDK class. I suggest you to use `Window` class that is a Flex container and already implements `IFocusManagerContainer`.

Comment: thanks for this answer. As I'm beginner can you explain to me how to modify FlexNativeWindow class/ Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did that you explain but only with get and set DefaultButton.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did that you explain but only with get and set DefaultButton. Is it necessery to implement all declared method. Other question, I use NativeWindow because I work with air and it's important for me to use native window option. So if it's possible to do the sale with window I'll be happy to know how. Thanks

Comment: You can implement `defaultButton` as an empty property that always returns `null`. I think that it's possible to reimplement Flex container logic in `NativeWindow` subclass however I can't imagine a task that would require that. Please tell us why do you want?